# Jenkins - I had configured MS Test plugin with jenkins, but Ms test displaying result -> starting execution. No tests to execute

Tags: jenkins

I had configured MSTest plugin in jenkins, but I am not able to run the unit automation tests. Actually the project is in TFS, where the unit tests are written. I had specified all .dll's path in Jenkins but Console output says **No tests to execute**

[image]

Comment: Loading Framework\Example.Tests\bin\Debug\Example.Tests.dll...
Starting execution...
No tests to execute.
even though tests are available and executed in TFS

Comment: No errors? or something else information?

Comment: 61 warnings 0 errors

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with MSTest and Jenkins. Can you add the screenshot of the settings for MS Test Plugin?

Comment: Please check the screenshot attached, I had replaced my original project name with Example for security reasons. However, I hope that doesn't bother.

Comment: The configuration looks the same as mine. Have you tried to run mstest for these files from cmd?

Comment: And can you also share the logs?

Comment: I had tried to execute these tests from CMD: It displays .Tests is not recognized as an internal or external command
operable program or batch file

Comment: Hey, as I am new to Jenkins I don't have much idea about logs. Can you guide me where I can find the logs. Moreover, is it possible to add a doc file in Stackoverflow